# c: extern variable is not retaining value

Tags: c, extern

I am using an extern bool variable. I have initialized it (to true) and want to use this value somewhere else in program. But the problem is, when went into another module, this true value is becoming false and when returned from that module (where the value was last seen true), then it turns to true.
I am not understanding why extern variable is behaving like this.
Does someone know about this?

I want extern variable to retain its value like it should be.

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve]?

Comment: You have two separate source files (translation units) where you want to use a variable declared in the other file. In the file where you make the original declaration, just declare a global variable as normal, e.g. `bool myvar;` and then set it to `true` in a function that runs before the `extern` reference to that is used. In the second file, declare `extern bool myvar;` At that point you can reference or set the value for `myvar` in either source file.

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is a bit broad, a short example may help cement the way `extern` works for you. Continuing from my comment, the original declaration of a variable you want to reference in another source file can be declared in any source. It should be global in scope.

Take for example a simple file we will call `source1.c` where we will declare two normal global variables `bool myvar` (representing your `bool` variable) and an `int access;` to use as as simple counter to show how the value of `myvar` is handled:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool myvar;     /* original declarations of myvar and access */
int access;     /* counter to show which output takes place */

void init()
{
  myvar = true;     /* initialization of myvar true - can be anywhere */
}

void show_myvar()
{
  /* output of myvar and access in file where they are decalred */
  printf ("%d myvar = %s\n", ++access, myvar ? "true" : "false");
}
```

Now in a separate source file, you want to be able to access or change the values in `myvar` or `access`, so you declare the variables as `extern` in any other source file that needs them. This tells the linker that the symbol was declared somewhere else and it will need to resolve the symbol before creating the final executable.

A short example that outputs the value of `myvar` from source1.c before it is initialized `true`, then initializes the value `true` and outputs from source1.c again showing the initialization took place. Next the values for both of the exten variables are access directly in the source2.c and modified. As a final confirmation, functions are called showing the direct change of the extern variables in source2 are reflected in source1 as well.

For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

extern bool myvar;    /* extern declarations of myvar and access */
extern int access;

void init();          /* function prototypes for functions from */
void show_myvar();    /* other source -- can be in separate header */

int main (void) {
  
  show_myvar();       /* show myvar before explicit initialization */
  init();             /* explicitly initialize myvar */
  show_myvar();       /* show initialization succeeded */
  
  /* ouput access and myvar directly in this source */
  printf ("%d myvar (main) = %s\n", ++access, myvar ? "true" : "false");
  
  myvar = false;      /* change the value in this source */
  show_myvar();       /* show value of myvar updated in other source */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

After compiling `source1.c` and `source2.c` together into an executable, the output would be:

```
$ ./bin/externexample
1 myvar = false
2 myvar = true
3 myvar (main) = true
4 myvar = false
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. This was just one short example that may help you understand the use of `extern`. It's not meant to be exhaustive in any way, but simply to cover the general use of `extern` between multiple source files.

There are other ways of defining constant values you want to reference in multiple sources. A common way is to `#define` a constant value in a header and then include the header in all sources that need it. However, depending on how you use the variable, a `#define` cannot have its address taken (it is a simple text-replacement made by the compiler). So if you need the address of the variable, that won't do.

Comment: I am doing somthing like this -
File 1
extern bool isCheched;
isCheched = ture;

File 2
Function() //function definition
//want to use value here but its false

Comment: @ER257 In `File1` if that is the original declaration it should be just `bool isChecked;` and  are you sure `isChecked = true;` is called in `File1` before your attempted read in `File2`? You can initialize in `File1` in the original definition as `book isChecked = true;` and that will ensure `isChecked` is never `false`.